# Adobe AIR slower than app.js and chrome in CSS animations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, air, google-chrome-app

Why do apps run slow on `AIR` as compared to `app.js` and `chrome`. I've tried to run a `js-jQuery` code which does a `slideToggle()` and found that the slide is a lot smoother in `app.js` and chrome as compared to `air`. I've also noticed the opening of `css+html+js` based popups in AIR is slower.

Why is it so?

Comment: i'm curious to know what other than AIR is slow (..by Adobe)

Comment: as far as I know, V8 is the fastest javascript interpreter. whilst the JS engine in webkit is slow. This might be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googles own V8 is way ahead of the JS engine in WebKit which is WebCore.

Here's an article on V8s performance:

http://techon.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/HONSHI/20090106/163615/